# Apache 2.4 SSL _default_ overriding virtualhost

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have an Apache 2.4 server that I have created a self-signed cert for testing https with a new client site. The problem I'm encountering is that the ssl.conf file's  is always loading for my site when I attempt to go to the defined virtualhost I set up in a separate vhosts.conf file.

Could someone please help me understand why the desired virtualhost is never loading and only the default is?

**My ssl.conf contents**

```
Listen 443 https

SSL Global Context
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog

SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
  ServerName localhost:443

  ErrorLog logs/default_ssl_error_log
  TransferLog logs/default_ssl_access_log
  LogLevel warn

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key

  <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Files>
  <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>

  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
     nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
     downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
      "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

**My virtualhost file content**

```
<VirtualHost demo.ffh.com:443>
  ServerAdmin   skittles@site.com
  ServerName    demo.ffh.com
  DocumentRoot  "/var/www/vhosts/ffh/public"

  RewriteEngine On
  # And THIS doesn't seem to be working at all!
  LogLevel debug rewrite:trace8

  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/ffh/public/">
    AllowOverride all
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    #Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    SSLRequireSSL On
  </Directory>

  SSLEngine on

  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ssl.key/demo_ffh.key
  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/httpd/ssl/ssl.crt/demo_ffh.crt

  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </FilesMatch>

  BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  CustomLog logs/ssl_ffh-access.log combined
  ErrorLog logs/ssl_ffh-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone see why the vhosts.conf site is being ignored in favor of the default? And how do I fix this? Been banging my head against a wall all day with this.

NOTE: "Probably worth calling out that I have tried the IP address and *:443 in the vhost.conf instead of the domain, but still no love."

Comment: FYI, according to the Apache documentation, "_ default _" is simply an alias for "*".

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost

Answer (score 2):

I have been having this issue and four solutions were to

1. change the paths to point at my cert and key (and any other intermediate certs?) directly in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

> This is ok if you have only a single SSL cert for the whole machine.

2. remove the entire default virtualhost entry from ssl.conf,

> This gives me the configuration in SSL.conf and allows me to determine
>   my own VirtualHost entries for multiple SSL certs (if necessary)

3. put the ssl.conf (alphabetically) after my desired conf file, which I named "vhosts.conf" (I changed ssl.conf to "vv.conf" to test this)

> This works as well for multiple SSL certs in my vhosts.conf file, but
>   makes me feel dirty because I'm changing names. I guess one could use
>   the conf.modules.d-meets-sitesenabled syntax of 010-vhosts.conf
>   020-ssl.conf and feel very slightly less dirty.

4. put my own cert and key in /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt and /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key

> Eh... maybe for some people.. I didn't like that though.

Comment: OK looks like we're just using 00-vhosts.conf to make sure our config goes first.  It was the least disruptive. I don't feel too dirty. Normal dirty.

Answer (score 1):

Okay...I guess I fixed it. O.o

I'm uncertain of exactly what it was that made this work, but the last couple things I did were;

1. I created a new self-signed cert and set the vhost config to use it and the respective key.
2. I then changed the virtualhost config to *:443.
3. Restarted the apache server. And VIOLA! What gives?!

Oh well...maybe lesson learned here?

Answer (score 0):

[Lets Encrypt Stopped Processing ssl.conf first](https://serverfault.com/questions/1013270/lets-encrypt-stopped-processing-ssl-conf-first)

I think I have the reverse problem. OP here wants Vhost file to be processed instead of ssl.conf.

I need ssl.conf processed before e.conf, like it was before. I don't understand why before ssl.conf was the default and no files in /etc/httpd/conf.d interfered, even if they were first alphabetically.

I think the solution for my case would be, reinstall, unless someone can provide a better solution.

Edit: I found a better solution than reinstalling (at least for now) [Lets Encrypt Stopped Processing ssl.conf first](https://serverfault.com/questions/1013270/lets-encrypt-stopped-processing-ssl-conf-first#comment1316069_1013282)  But I think it's a hack and still looking for better options.

EDIT: The fix to my problem was rename the `em-le-ssl.conf` file, not `em.conf` to something after ssl.conf alphabetically. To fix the problem here, the asker would have to rename their vHost-le-ssl.conf file to something before ssl.conf.

Comment: sysadmin1138, Why would you thank me then remove my post. Contradictory. Either way, I fixed my post to be an answer and not just a question to a question. I would have posted it as a comment, but it won't let me yet...

Answer (score 0):

It seems indeed (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4762977/7683041)) that you need to put

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

for your site/configuration file (and each of them) instead of

```
<VirtualHost demo.ffh.com:443>
```

The resolution will be done by the `ServerName` parameter.